# In C# ExcelApp destructor I get the error 'The App does not exist in the current context'

Tags: c#

In C# an ExcelApp is created in the constructor, when I try to use the same App in the destructor I get the squiggly line saying that 'The App does not exist in the current context'

```cs
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace Analysis
{
    class OutputFile
    {

        OutputFile()
        {
            Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
        }

        interface IOutputFile
        {

        }

        ~OutputFile()
        {
            ExcelApp.Close();
            ExcelApp.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's true, it doesn't exist in that context. Your `ExcelApp` variable is created in the constructor, and is out of scope by the time the constructor exits. Did you mean to make it a class member instead?

Comment: As an aside, destructor in C# is not guaranteed to run at all; if `ExcelApp` is an `IDisposable`, then `using(var excelApp = new Excel.Application()) { /* code */ }` is a recommended approach.

Comment: Thank you for replying. How can I modify the code to do what I am trying to achieve ? How can I make OutputFileClass to do ExcelApp.Close() and
        ExcelApp.Quit() at the end of my program ?

Comment: I changed the ExcelApp to be a class member, rather than inside a constructor, like you mentioned. Thank you CoolBoots, it works.class OutputFile
    {
           
        Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
        interface IOutputFile
        {

        }

        ~OutputFile()
        {
            ExcelApp.Workbooks.Close();
            ExcelApp.Quit();
        }
    }

Comment: See my answer; you should implement `IDisposable` on your `OutputFile` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 problems:

- Your object `ExcelApp` is only scoped to the constructor, but looks like to it should be a class member or a property.
- Finalizers are not the right solution for this sort of use case in C#; implement `IDisposable` interface instead:

```
class OutputFile : IDisposable
{
   Excel.Application ExcelApp { get; set; } 

   public OutputFile() 
   { 
      ExcelApp = new Excel.Application(); 
   }

   public void Dispose() 
   { 
      ExcelApp.Close(); 
      ExcelApp.Quit(); 
   }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
using(var outputFile = new OutputFile())
{
   // do stuff with output file 
}
```

Once `outputFile` goes out of scope (at the end of the `using` block), the `Dispose()` method will be called by the Garbage Collector (GC). Note, this will happen even if an exception occurs inside the `using` block, as this code is a shorthand for:

```cs
var outputFile = new OutputFile();
try
{
   // do stuff with output file 
}
finally
{
    outputFile.Dispose();
}
```

Since you're new to C#, I will link the documentation references for [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement), [IDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=netframework-4.8), and [Finalizers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/destructor)

Happy learning!

Comment: Excellent, Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for. I am new to C# coding.

Comment: @user2754735 Awesome, glad my answer helped you! I added a bit more explanation and documentation links - happy coding!